# Convert a web site to xml?

Tags: php, xml

I am using this code to get content of a web site:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/');
```

And for now, I want to convert `$data` to an XML object to parse it easily. For example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<html>
    <body>
         <div id='main'>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thank in advance

Comment: Just use DOMDocument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881255/generating-xml-from-html-list-using-php

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several classes and API's built into PHP and ready to use.

Take a look here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php

Since your using the source of a website, you'd be best using DOMDocument and loading it as HTML (since that's what it is).

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://example.com/');
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML( $data );
```

Comment: your answer is ambiguous. it is not giving result

Comment: You probably wanted to type $dom->loadHTML( $data ); because $dom is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to convert it to xml? You can parse it as html easily as well..

For example just use http://php.net/manual/pl/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Because I want to convert it to array or use part of a web page as an output, I need it as a XML