# PHP function for convert html content to xml format,With perfect directory structure.HTML must get from direct URL of a website

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

Using a DOM module. get html content from url and convert these html to XML format

```
<?php

$dom= new DOMDocument();


$html = $dom->loadHTMLFile('http://example.com/');
echo $html;

?>
```

Comment: Show some output/code etc? What is your question?

Comment: hi @Hassaan what i am trying to achieve is that. if i put a website url( Ex: http://stackoverflow.com/ ) i need to get all the html flow in xml file.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: this is the conclusion of what i have done, i need to convert this $html to xml format

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10473875/converting-html-to-xml or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415571/convert-a-web-site-to-xml - they should give you some useful guidance

Comment: @RamRaider : i tried those, but i need a perfect function for that