# Return external wordpress page as XML Object

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, parsing, cakephp

I have a CakePHP site for a client, but with the sites blog run on Wordpress (I just redirect to the WP site for the blog).  The client now wants a section of the homepage to pull in a snippet from the blog and I am wondering what is the best way to do this.  I am currently trying this...

```
 function getPosts($feed_url) {

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url); // get XML string
    $feed_object = new xml($content); // load XML string into object
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content); // load XML string into object
}

getPosts("example.com");
```

The 'file_get_content' is working great and actually pulling in the html but I cannot get that html into xml.  My error message is 'String could not be parsed as XML'.  Anyone know the best way to go about this?

Comment: Have you take a look to this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881255/generating-xml-from-html-list-using-php/4881456#4881456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [simplexml_load_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) directly.

```
function getPosts($feed_url) {
    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url); // get XML string
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($content); 
    return $xml;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am getting the following errors when I try that: Warning (2): simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : StartTag: invalid element name [APP/View/Themed/Endo/Nodes/home.ctp, line 53]

Comment: Actually that's not correct.  Francesco you're answer is correct but it is not giving me all of the data from that page.  Why am I limited in the data that is returned in the simpleXML?  For example, I can easily grab the post title but the description or excerpt is not included in the XML Object? Any idea?